# valueChanged gui List executing twice

Tags: swing, user-interface, groovy, selection

When making a selection on this simple gui list I am getting valueChanged to execute twice once when mouse down and once when mouse up.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.*
import java.swing.*
import javax.swing.*


def main(){
    new SwingBuilder().edt {
        frame(title:'Testing', pack:true, show:true) {
            vbox {
                panel(){
                    textbox = label(text:'null')
                }
                panel(){
                    listing = list(valueChanged:{
                            mess(listing.selectedValue);// this code runs twice
                        },
                        listData: ['test','another','test','and','again'])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def mess(mytext){
    new SwingBuilder().edt {
        frame(title:'Message', pack:true, show:true){
            vbox {
                panel(){
                    label(text:mytext)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

main();
```

I have looked for other questions similar to this one on stackoverflow to no avail if it is a duplicate I'm sorry and I will remove it but I don't believe it is. All I'm trying to do it get this to not execute on mouse up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with a Swing JList you get two valueChanged events when the user clicks on a row.

The first click will have `event.valueIsAdjusting == true` to indicate the user is in the process of changing the value, and the second event will have `event.valueIsAdjusting == false` to show the selection has been made (see the [evaluation section of this bug report* here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4323107) and the event [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29))

Changing:

```
 valueChanged:{
   mess(listing.selectedValue);// this code runs twice
 }
```

To:

```
 valueChanged:{ event ->
   if( !event.valueIsAdjusting ) mess(listing.selectedValue)
 }
```

Should fix this...

(* It should be noted that this is not a bug, as can be seen by it's closure status) :-)

---

#### edit

To clear the selection, you can change `main()` to:

```
def main() {
  def data = ['test','another','test','and','again']
  def codeFired = false
  new SwingBuilder().edt {
    frame(title:'Testing', pack:true, show:true) {
      vbox {
        panel(){
          textbox = label(text:'null')
        }
        panel(){
          listing = list listData: data, valueChanged: { event ->
            if( !event.valueIsAdjusting && !codeFired ) {
              mess( listing.selectedValue )
              codeFired = true
              listing.clearSelection()
              codeFired = false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew that it was not a bug but I had no idea how to combat this.

Comment: My next question would be I still want the user to be able to click and get the info but it doesn't have to stay selected how do I deselect it after the event is executed?

Comment: I believe you would need to set some sort of flag variable to true (to indicate you are setting the value programatically, then set the selected index, then set the flag back to false. Then check for the flag in the event handler, and don't do anything if it's set (otherwise if I remember rightly, you get infinite loops)... Does that make any sense? Not at a computer right now...

Comment: It worked perfect thank you very much. Though I tried without the codeFired it wasn't the infinite loop but it did fire both on down and up again... So still thanks :]